# How to capture the print of the subprocess while polling with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python-3.x, logging, input, printing, subprocess

I'm creating a small gui under ubuntu which starts a subprocess and prints the log in a text box. In my function, it calls another program using subprocess.POpen and print the log of the subprocess in a tkinter GUI. I found the printing works fine except when the subprocess has an input statement, which asks the user to input some characters. It seems that information printed in the subprocess is not captured in my function.

Below is the code in my funciton:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(f'xxx.par xxx.yml', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, bufsize=1, text=True)
while p.poll() is None and not self.exit:
    msg = p.stdout.readline().strip()  # read a line from the process output
    if msg:
        self.log_area.insert(tk.END, msg + "\n")
```

And in the subprocess, it has the following statements asking for user input:

```
 print("Enter your name: ", end="")
 your_name = input()
```

How can I make my function work so that I can capture the print of "Enter your name: " and then type the characters and pass them to the subprocess, just like in the terminal?